# Does the GT9800 support compute_20?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have `NVIDIA GT9800` and `CUDA-program(sample)`. 
If I specify code generation as `compute_20,sm_20` then the error,

> invalid device function

occurrs. I have no issues with `compute_11,sm_11`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No it is not supported.

Comment: @talonmies, can you give some link? or how to find such information for other devices?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: @talonmies, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9800GT only supports sm 1.0~1.3, Femi can support sm 2.0, please refer the Compute capability table in wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA